# UPDATE with multiple JOIN on CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, postgres-12

I am writing an `UPDATE` sql query within **Postgres 12**.

The query is very complex and it needs to contain `JOIN` and `CASE` in order to work. I can not get my head around it so far. I need to update an `approval_status` column on the comment_response table.

The `team_member_manager` table indicates who needs to approve comments and they are only valid ones (even if there are more others in the `post_comment_response_approval`)

There are 4 Cases I need:

- If everyone who needs to submit responses has submitted an approval, then the status - should be approved.
- If there are no associated team_member_manager records, the status also should be approved.
- If anyone has rejected it, the status should be rejected.
- Otherwise, the status should be pending.

Here are table structures with right values.

`post_comment_response` table:

| id | post_comment_id | comment | approval_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1173 | Hello World | NULL |

`post_comment` table:

| id | post_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1173 | 652 |

`post` table:

| id | message_id | team_member_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 652 | 110 | 60735 |

`team_member_manager` table:

| id | managing_team_member_id | managed_team_member_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 68893 | 60735 |
| 56 | 68893 | 60736 |

`team_member` table:

| id | team_id | member_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 68893 | 91 | 1 |

`post_comment_response_approval` table:

| id | post_comment_response_id | team_member_id | approved | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 1 | 60735 | true | This one should be included |
| 70 | 1 | 666 | true | This should not |
| 70 | 1 | 60736 | false | This should be included |

*NOTE: I'am defining how is manager and who is managed member by doing `JOIN`
`managing_team_member_id` is the one with defined value (91)
`managed_team_member_id` value I want to get by JOINing **post_comment → post***

My sql statement and `JOIN`s are working as it should but I got stuck on how to implement them properly with `CASE`s. Can someone please help?

```
UPDATE post_comment_response pcr
SET
approval_status = CASE WHEN 'first case'= 'approved'
                  WHEN 'second case' = 'approved',
                  WHEN 'third case' = 'rejected'
                  ELSE 'pending'
JOIN post_comment pc ON pc.id = 1173
JOIN post p ON p.id = pc.post_id
JOIN team_member_manager tmm ON tmm.managed_team_member_id = p.team_member_id
JOIN team_member mgr ON mgr.id = tmm.managing_team_member_id
WHERE mgr.team_id = 91;
```

Comment: 1/ your first `JOIN`should be replaced by `FROM` 2/ `ON pc.id = 1173` is not sql ompliant, to be replaced by `AND pc.id = 1173` in the `WHERE` clause 3/ The table `post_comment_response_approval` doesn't appear in the `JOIN` clause, is it an omission ?

Comment: In which table to you see that there are zero, one or more managers who have to approve a given comment ?

Comment: I know, this is just the basic example of how I would implement the idea but as I am pretty new at this do not know who to finish it. Can you please help? Thanks for replaying @Edouard

Comment: In the table by one sql execution there can be one  managing_team_member but can be related to various managed_team_member... @Edouard

Comment: Difficult to follow you; it would be valuable if you can add several rows in the different tables so that to illustrate the 4 cases you want to implement.

Comment: I've added more rows in team_member_manager and team_member_manager_approval tables.. So by the input i provided, bassucly if all related  rows from team_member_manager_approval are approved then approve, if there are no rows also approve, if even one of them is false, then reject, otherwise pending.. @Edouard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"if all related rows from team_member_manager_approval are approved then approve, if even one of them is false, then reject"*

To get this result, you need to use the aggregate function `bool_and` applied to the column `approved` of table `post_comment_response_approval` while grouping the rows on `post_comment_response.id`

*"if there are no rows also approve"*

To get this result, you need to `LEFT JOIN` the table `post_comment_response_approval` with other tables so that if no row matches, then a NULL value will be populated for the columns coming from that table.

Then you can use a `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END` statement to convert the boolean result of `bool_and` into a text : true => 'approve', false => 'reject'.
If no row exists in table `post_comment_response_approval` then `bool_and(...)` will return `NULL` and `COALESCE(bool_and(...), true)` will return `true` so that to select the 'approve' value.

As you can't use an aggregate function directly in the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE`, then you have to implement the query in a `cte`, and to refer to the `cte` result in the `UPDATE`.

Starting from your data sample, and trying to follow your business logic, the solution to update the `approval_status` in the `post_comment_response` table and which corresponds to `post_comment = 1173` and `team_member.team_id = 91` is :

```
WITH list AS (
SELECT 
       pcr.id, pcr.post_comment_id, pcr.comment
     , CASE WHEN COALESCE(bool_and(pcra.approved), true) THEN 'approve' WHEN NOT bool_and(pcra.approved) THEN 'reject' ELSE 'pending' END AS approval_status
  FROM post_comment_response pcr
  LEFT JOIN post_comment_response_approval pcra ON pcra.post_comment_response_id = pcr.id
  JOIN team_member_manager tmm ON tmm.managed_team_member_id = pcra.team_member_id
  JOIN team_member tm ON tm.id = tmm.managing_team_member_id
 WHERE pcr.post_comment_id = 1173
   AND tm.team_id = 91
  GROUP BY pcr.id, pcr.post_comment_id, pcr.comment
)
UPDATE post_comment_response pcr
   SET approval_status = l.approval_status
  FROM list l
 WHERE pcr.id = l.id ;
```

But you can also update all the rows of the `post_comment_response` table at once with the following query :

```
WITH list AS (
SELECT 
       pcr.id, pcr.post_comment_id, pcr.comment
     , CASE WHEN COALESCE(bool_and(pcra.approved), true) THEN 'approve' WHEN NOT bool_and(pcra.approved) THEN 'reject' ELSE 'pending' END AS approval_status
  FROM post_comment_response pcr
  LEFT JOIN post_comment_response_approval pcra ON pcra.post_comment_response_id = pcr.id
  JOIN team_member_manager tmm ON tmm.managed_team_member_id = pcra.team_member_id
  JOIN team_member tm ON tm.id = tmm.managing_team_member_id
  JOIN post_comment pc ON pc.id = pcr.post_comment_id
  JOIN post p ON p.id = pc.post_id
  JOIN team_member_manager tmm2 ON tmm2.managed_team_member_id = p.team_member_id AND tmm2.managing_team_member_id = tm.id
 GROUP BY pcr.id, pcr.post_comment_id, pcr.comment
)
UPDATE post_comment_response pcr
   SET approval_status = l.approval_status
  FROM list l
 WHERE pcr.id = l.id ;
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4qKKK_Ct)

Comment: A load of thanks for this. I saved your answer as I need to get into it a little more in detail in order to figure out everything you did. Thanks a lot for your time and effort! I tested it on my side, it works! @Edouard

Comment: And also this CASE covers all cases except one. On first one we are returning approved even if the field is NULL.. Which is okay but we also need a CASE where we want to set approved even if no row was SELECTED (If there are no associated team_member_manager records) @Edouard

Comment: in order to set to 'approve' when no rows selected from `team_member_manager ` you can try to `LEFT JOIN` the table `team_member_manager`

Comment: It is already JOINed? Did you mean to use another SELECT with JOIN in the separate CASE? @Edouard

Comment: No just put `LEFT JOIN team_member_manager tmm ON tmm.managed_team_member_id = pcra.team_member_id` in the `FROM` clause instead of `JOIN team_member_manager tmm ON tmm.managed_team_member_id = pcra.team_member_id`

Comment: I am not sure I understand? To put LEFT JOIN in FROM clause? @Edouard

Comment: yes just replace `JOIN` by `LEFT JOIN` in front of `team_member_manager tmm `